# Elastic Email SPF configuration on AWS Route 53

Tags: email, dns, spf, amazon-route53

I am currently attempting to set up a verified domain in Elastic Email and I use AWS Route 53 as my DNS provider.  I've created a SPF and TXT record (since SPF doesn't seem to work) pointing to:

```
"v=spf1 a mx include:_spf.elasticemail.com ~all"
```

but everytime I login into verify SPF I get an error message indicating the check cannot find the appropriate record to verify my domain?

> SPF Validation Finding TXT records at host: spiritshop.com
>
> include:_spf.elasticemail.com not found in valid SPF record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SPF records are unfortunately not valid. You included the host _spf.elasticemail.com twice.

Try this SPF checker: http://spf.myisp.ch It will show you what's wrong with your records.

Comment: Hi Benjamin, your permanent linking to your site  http://spf.myisp.ch might seen as spam.

Comment: I'm always trying to find out what the problem is and link to the SPF checker to help making sure the SPF entry is valid. Unfortunately I haven't seen any other SPF checker which does such extensive checks.

Comment: Dmarcian's SPF checker does extensive checks, and also features the graphical layout. https://dmarcian.com/spf-survey/

Comment: There is an issue with this tool, in the way it counts the amount of queries. The SPF standard states 10 query mechanisms (ie. 1 "mx" entry will count as 1, even though it may cover 4 MX records each with 1 DNS lookup). Tv2.dk uses 8 queries/mechanisms f.ex., but this tool claims 10 queries. This tool counts the MX lookup as 2 queries, where it should be 1, and the initial lookup itself as 1 where it doesn't count.

Comment: The way the lookups are counted has been changed. I believe it is correct now.

Answer (score 0):

in my case there was an issue with alias being defined in TXT, but not present as A record, so I had to add it first.
This tool helped [EasyDMARC](https://easydmarc.com/tools/spf-lookup?domain=yourdomain.com)